# Replace `&` with `\&` in R

Tags: r, string, replace, stringr

I want to replace `&` with `\&` in `R&D`.

How can I do it?

`stringr::str_replace("R&D","&","\\&")` still gives `R&D` instead of `R\&D`, I don't know why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\&` has a special meaning in the replacement value of `str_replace` (it refers to the matched text). To avoid this special meaning, double up the backslashes to escape them, too.

The following therefore works:

```
stringr::str_replace("R&D", "&", "\\\\&")
```

Comment: No it doesn't. It shows up as `"R\\&D"`

Comment: @robertspierre Yes, that is correct: it shows the *string literal value*, including surrounding quotes and backslash as escape. This is how *every* string is displayed in R. Use `writeLines()` or `cat()` to display it properly.

Answer (score 2):

@Konrad Rudolph already gave a perfect explanation. If you want to print a single backslash you could use `cat`. Here is an alternative using `gsub`:

```r
cat(gsub("&", r"(\\&)", "R&D"))
#> R\&D
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>